# Loris package installing issue

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to install Loris package [link](http://www.cerlsoundgroup.org/Loris/#doc) which is a library also for Python (my language). I have installed the package through bash commands in my OSX 10.12 system following these steps:

1. `cd` to the directory containing the package's source code and type
    `./configure` to configure the package for your system.  If you're
    using `csh` on an old version of System V, you might need to type
    `sh ./configure` instead to prevent `csh` from trying to execute
    `configure` itself.

   Running `configure' takes awhile.  While running, it prints some
    messages telling which features it is checking for.

   2. Type `make' to compile the package.
   3. Optionally, type `make check' to run any self-tests that come with
      the package.
   4. Type `make install' to install the programs and any data files and
      documentation.
   5. You can remove the program binaries and object files from the
      source code directory by typing **make clean**.  To also remove the
      files that `configure` created (so you can compile the package for
      a different kind of computer), type `make distclean`.  There is
      also a `make maintainer-clean` target, but that is intended mainly
      for the package's developers.  If you use it, you may have to get
      all sorts of other programs in order to regenerate files that came
      with the distribution.

The problem is that when I run both python 2.7 IDLE and the Atom editor it says that the module named Loris was not found. By default, `make install` will install the package's files in
`/usr/local/bin`,`/usr/local/man`.
Is this the problem? How can I install properly this library?